# How to delete and insert rows based on a column with SQLAlchemy in Python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My code reads some excel files and appends them to a list, also adding a column to extract the file name. Then it concatenates everything and sends it to a table.

```
all_df_list = []

for file in files_list:  
     #reads and appends excel files
     frame = pd.read_excel(pd.read_excel(file, header=0, engine='openpyxl'))
     frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(file)
     all_df_list.append(frame)

xls=pd.concat(all_df_list)
xls.to_sql(table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

This code works just fine and the output is something like this:

| Column A | Column B | filname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | file 01.xlsx |
| Second | row | file 02.xlsx |

What I need now is to alter my code to check for that filename in the column ( `(os.path.basename(file)` ) and either overwrite for only those rows or delete rows where  `filename =  (os.path.basename(file)` and then execute the code above. Like, if that filename exists, delete the corresponding rows and execute that code above, something like that.

Any ideas how I can do that? I'm using create_engine method from sqlalchemy to access the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understand, you want to delete the rows based on the filename before inserting the rows once again.
Maybe this will help you

```
engine.execute("DELETE FROM %s WHERE filename = %s", (table, file))
```

if file is the full path , you should use`os.path.basename(file)`instead

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Assuming you want to minimize the work done on the database side and do as much as possible using dataframes, this will achieve the same result as my original answer (further down).

**Initial state:**
For testing purposes, initialize the main database table, `SomeTable`, to simulate a situation in which it has been updated previously:

```py
xls=pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'Column A':['First'], 'Column B':['row'], 'filename':['file 01.xlsx']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'Column A':['Second'], 'Column B':['row'], 'filename':['file 02.xlsx']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'Column A':['Third'], 'Column B':['row'], 'filename':['file 03.xlsx']})
])
xls.to_sql("SomeTable", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

Contents of `SomeTable`:

```
  Column A Column B      filename
0    First      row  file 01.xlsx
1   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
2    Third      row  file 03.xlsx
```

**Source of updates:**
Specify the files to use to update `SomeTable` in the database and load these into `dfBasenames`:

```py
files_list = ['file 01.xlsx', 'file 04.xlsx']

import os

# accumulate new file names in files_list into "new_file"
basenames = set()
for file in files_list:
    basenames.add(os.path.basename(file))
dfBasenames = pd.DataFrame({'filename': list(basenames)})
```

Contents of `dfBasenames`:

```
       filename
0  file 04.xlsx
1  file 01.xlsx
```

**Delete stale rows:**
Delete rows in `df` with filename column value found in `dfBasenames`:

```py
df = df.join(dfBasenames.assign(is_stale=True).set_index('filename'), on='filename')
df = df[df['is_stale'].isna()].drop(columns=['is_stale'])
```

Contents of `df`:

```
  Column A Column B      filename
1   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
2    Third      row  file 03.xlsx
```

Note that the original row with `filename == "file 01.xlsx"` has been deleted.

**Update `df` from latest files:**
Aggregate rows found in Excel files in `files_list` and `concat` them together with non-stale rows in `df`:

```py
all_df_list = []
for file in files_list:  
    #reads and appends excel files
    frame = pd.read_excel(file)
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(file)
    print(f'\nfile {file}:\n{frame}')
    all_df_list.append(frame)
df = pd.concat([df] + all_df_list)
```

Contents of `df`:

```
  Column A Column B      filename
1   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
2    Third      row  file 03.xlsx
0   1.a.01   1.b.01  file 01.xlsx
1   1.a.02   1.b.02  file 01.xlsx
0   4.a.01   4.b.01  file 04.xlsx
1   4.a.02   4.b.02  file 04.xlsx
```

**Commit changes to database:**
Overwrite `SomeTable` in database using `df`:

```py
df.to_sql("SomeTable", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

Contents of `SomeTable`:

```
  Column A Column B      filename
0   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
1    Third      row  file 03.xlsx
2   1.a.01   1.b.01  file 01.xlsx
3   1.a.02   1.b.02  file 01.xlsx
4   4.a.01   4.b.01  file 04.xlsx
5   4.a.02   4.b.02  file 04.xlsx
```

**Full test code:**

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
connectable = 'sqlite:///foo.db'
engine = create_engine(connectable)

# For testing purposes only, initialize SomeTable so it's not empty
xls=pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'Column A':['First'], 'Column B':['row'], 'filename':['file 01.xlsx']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'Column A':['Second'], 'Column B':['row'], 'filename':['file 02.xlsx']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'Column A':['Third'], 'Column B':['row'], 'filename':['file 03.xlsx']})
])
xls.to_sql("SomeTable", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=10000)

# read and print SomeTable for verification of initial state
df = pd.read_sql_table("SomeTable", connectable) 
print('======== VERIFY INITIAL STATE: read_sql_table("SomeTable"):')
print(df)

# specify files to use to update SomeTable in the database
files_list = ['file 01.xlsx', 'file 04.xlsx']

import os

# accumulate new file names in files_list into "new_file"
basenames = set()
for file in files_list:
    basenames.add(os.path.basename(file))
dfBasenames = pd.DataFrame({'filename': list(basenames)})
print('======== VERIFY FILENAMES TO UPDATE FROM:')
print(dfBasenames)

# delete rows in SomeTable copy with filename column found in dfBasenames
df = df.join(dfBasenames.assign(is_stale=True).set_index('filename'), on='filename')
df = df[df['is_stale'].isna()].drop(columns=['is_stale'])
print('======== VERIFY DELETION OF ROWS MATCHING NEW FILENAMES:')
print(df)

# aggregate rows found in Excel files in dfBasenames into all_df_list and concat to remaining non-stale rows of SomeTable copy
all_df_list = []
for file in files_list:  
    #reads and appends excel files
    frame = pd.read_excel(file)
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(file)
    print(f'\nfile {file}:\n{frame}')
    all_df_list.append(frame)
df = pd.concat([df] + all_df_list)
print('======== VERIFY UPDATED DF READY TO COMMIT TO DB:')
print(df)

# overwrite SomeTable in database
df.to_sql("SomeTable", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=10000)

# read and print table for verification of correct result
df = pd.read_sql_table("SomeTable", connectable) 
print('======== VERIFY UPDATED TABLE: read_sql_table("SomeTable"):')
print(df)
```

**Test output:**

```
======== VERIFY INITIAL STATE: read_sql_table("SomeTable"):
  Column A Column B      filename
0    First      row  file 01.xlsx
1   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
2    Third      row  file 03.xlsx
======== VERIFY FILENAMES TO UPDATE FROM:
       filename
0  file 04.xlsx
1  file 01.xlsx
======== VERIFY DELETION OF ROWS MATCHING NEW FILENAMES:
  Column A Column B      filename
1   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
2    Third      row  file 03.xlsx

file file 01.xlsx:
  Column A Column B      filename
0   1.a.01   1.b.01  file 01.xlsx
1   1.a.02   1.b.02  file 01.xlsx

file file 04.xlsx:
  Column A Column B      filename
0   4.a.01   4.b.01  file 04.xlsx
1   4.a.02   4.b.02  file 04.xlsx
======== VERIFY UPDATED DF READY TO COMMIT TO DB:
  Column A Column B      filename
1   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
2    Third      row  file 03.xlsx
0   1.a.01   1.b.01  file 01.xlsx
1   1.a.02   1.b.02  file 01.xlsx
0   4.a.01   4.b.01  file 04.xlsx
1   4.a.02   4.b.02  file 04.xlsx
======== VERIFY UPDATED TABLE: read_sql_table("SomeTable"):
  Column A Column B      filename
0   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
1    Third      row  file 03.xlsx
2   1.a.01   1.b.01  file 01.xlsx
3   1.a.02   1.b.02  file 01.xlsx
4   4.a.01   4.b.01  file 04.xlsx
5   4.a.02   4.b.02  file 04.xlsx
```

---

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Here is a way to do what you've asked.

**Initial state:**
(Same as in UPDATED ANSWER above.)

**Source of updates:**
Specify the files to use to update `SomeTable` in the database and load these into a temporary database table `new_file`:

```py
files_list = ['file 01.xlsx', 'file 04.xlsx']
basenames = set()
for file in files_list:
    basenames.add(os.path.basename(file))
dfBasenames = pd.DataFrame({'filename': list(basenames)})
dfBasenames.to_sql("new_file", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

Contents of `new_file`:

```
       filename
0  file 01.xlsx
1  file 04.xlsx
```

**Delete stale rows:**
Delete rows in `SomeTable` with filename column value found in `new_file` table:

```py
with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute('delete from SomeTable where exists (select 1 from new_file where new_file.filename = SomeTable.filename)')
```

Contents of `SomeTable`:

```
  Column A Column B      filename
0   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
1    Third      row  file 03.xlsx
```

Note that the original row with `filename == "file 01.xlsx"` has been deleted.

**Update the database from latest files:**
Aggregate rows found in Excel files in `files_list` and append them to `SomeTable`:

```py
all_df_list = []
for file in files_list:  
    #reads and appends excel files
    frame = pd.read_excel(file)
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(file)
    all_df_list.append(frame)
xls = pd.concat(all_df_list)
xls.to_sql("SomeTable", con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)
```

Contents of `SomeTable`:

```
  Column A Column B      filename
0   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
1    Third      row  file 03.xlsx
2   1.a.01   1.b.01  file 01.xlsx
3   1.a.02   1.b.02  file 01.xlsx
4   4.a.01   4.b.01  file 04.xlsx
5   4.a.02   4.b.02  file 04.xlsx
```

---

**Full test code:**
Test code (with print statements) is:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
connectable = 'sqlite:///foo.db'
engine = create_engine(connectable)

# For testing purposes only, initialize SomeTable so it's not empty
xls=pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({'Column A':['First'], 'Column B':['row'], 'filename':['file 01.xlsx']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'Column A':['Second'], 'Column B':['row'], 'filename':['file 02.xlsx']}),
    pd.DataFrame({'Column A':['Third'], 'Column B':['row'], 'filename':['file 03.xlsx']})
])
xls.to_sql("SomeTable", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=10000)

# read and print SomeTable for verification of initial state
df = pd.read_sql_table("SomeTable", connectable) 
print('======== VERIFY INITIAL STATE: read_sql_table("SomeTable"):')
print(df)

# specify files to use to update SomeTable in the database
files_list = ['file 01.xlsx', 'file 04.xlsx']

import os

# accumulate new file names in files_list into "new_file"
basenames = set()
for file in files_list:
    basenames.add(os.path.basename(file))
dfBasenames = pd.DataFrame({'filename': list(basenames)})
dfBasenames.to_sql("new_file", con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=10000)

# read and print table for verification of correct result
df = pd.read_sql_table("new_file", connectable) 
print('======== VERIFY FILENAMES TO UPDATE FROM: read_sql_table("new_file"):')
print(df)

# delete rows in SomeTable with filename column found in new_file table
with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute('delete from SomeTable where exists (select 1 from new_file where new_file.filename = SomeTable.filename)')

# read and print table for verification of correct result
df = pd.read_sql_table("SomeTable", connectable) 
print('======== VERIFY DELETION OF ROWS MATCHING NEW FILENAMES: read_sql_table("SomeTable"):')
print(df)

# aggregate rows found in Excel files in files_list into all_df_list
all_df_list = []
for file in files_list:  
    #reads and appends excel files
    frame = pd.read_excel(file)
    frame['filename'] = os.path.basename(file)
    print(f'\nfile {file}:\n{frame}')
    all_df_list.append(frame)

# append rows in all_df_list to SomeTable
xls = pd.concat(all_df_list)
xls.to_sql("SomeTable", con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000)

# read and print table for verification of correct result
df = pd.read_sql_table("SomeTable", connectable) 
print('======== VERIFY UPDATED TABLE: read_sql_table("SomeTable"):')
print(df)
```

**Test output:**

```
======== VERIFY INITIAL STATE: read_sql_table("SomeTable"):
  Column A Column B      filename
0    First      row  file 01.xlsx
1   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
2    Third      row  file 03.xlsx
======== VERIFY FILENAMES TO UPDATE FROM: read_sql_table("new_file"):
       filename
0  file 01.xlsx
1  file 04.xlsx
======== VERIFY DELETION OF ROWS MATCHING NEW FILENAMES: read_sql_table("SomeTable"):
  Column A Column B      filename
0   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
1    Third      row  file 03.xlsx

file file 01.xlsx:
  Column A Column B      filename
0   1.a.01   1.b.01  file 01.xlsx
1   1.a.02   1.b.02  file 01.xlsx

file file 04.xlsx:
  Column A Column B      filename
0   4.a.01   4.b.01  file 04.xlsx
1   4.a.02   4.b.02  file 04.xlsx
======== VERIFY UPDATED TABLE: read_sql_table("SomeTable"):
  Column A Column B      filename
0   Second      row  file 02.xlsx
1    Third      row  file 03.xlsx
2   1.a.01   1.b.01  file 01.xlsx
3   1.a.02   1.b.02  file 01.xlsx
4   4.a.01   4.b.01  file 04.xlsx
5   4.a.02   4.b.02  file 04.xlsx
```